# right iptables configuration to run application in https mode and force https mode

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2

I am trying to make my application run in https mode in my production env, which is an ec2 instance with ubuntu, in amazon web services, but i'm having a hard time in figure out the right iptable config.

Could one someone point what is the right iptable configuration that i need?

I am using:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || '443');
```

And i have the HTTP, HTTPS and TCP ports open in the security groups.

I know i need create iptables rules in the server, but i don't know which one exactly, i already try to setup, and was working in the HTTPS, but i want be able to forward http requests to https, and this was not happening when i setup.

I try use also:

```
function requireHTTPS(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
  }
  next();
}
app.use(requireHTTPS);
```

But didn't work.

Thanks very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in the wrong place is all:

You need an HTTPD listening on port 443 to serve as a proxy that sits in front of your application for the redirect to work, otherwise you need the middleware package that allows Node.JS to host an HTTPS (with certificate exchange, etc) service.

You can use Apache HTTPd, nginx, or lighttpd to do a "proxy" to your application to enable HTTPS without changing your code (the unsecured handoff ("last leg") can be handled over a pipe, it doesn't even need to go over public net.)

Comment: I'd also strongly advise against trying to use iptables at all.  Amazon's EC2 [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) are effectively a virtual firewall.  By using iptables on top of Security Groups you're just going to end up confusing yourself down the line.